# I want to save the RGB and Depth data as frames by using Kinect

Tags: c#, matlab, kinect

I want to save the RGB and Depth data as frames by using Kinect. I have no experience in C# as I work on matlab. Can anyone suggest me easier way to do this task. I need to do this to build a dataset of depth videos for activity recognition. The samples that are provided with Kinect SDK only saves one frame after pressing a button. I need to save continuous frames to register an activity. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use the Kinect studio software? It was made available at the same time that Miscrosoft released the SDK 1.5.

You can download it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/developer-downloads.aspx) (or using this [link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=255120): direct download of the Kinect for Windows Developer Toolkit containing KinectStudio)

It can register the RGB, the Depth frames as well as the Skeleton frame by frame, and you can save them to **.xed** files. and you can re-play those frames (useful for testing without having to stand up and sit down every three seconds) or [use it for the training phase of machine learning algo (see slide 15).](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28066)

Here is a snapshot of the application:

[image: Kinect studio]

For your situation that's what I'd use.

Comment: I would like to import this data to Matlab for testing purposes. I dont think Matlab has a codec for .xed files. So how I do that?

Comment: I like the blue square covering your face:)

Comment: @user1502981 the format is not even public http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/kinectsdk/thread/c9cf94ad-1d39-4287-aacf-87bd68387fb1

Answer (score 3):

You can edit some of the samples given in the SDK to save continuous PNG frames.
In particular, DepthBasics has a method (ButtonScreenShotClick) that is called each time the user clicks the button.  If you make a duplicate of the method with no parameters and then call it everytime you want to save a image, you should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the depth streams from the Kinect or from recorded XED using the [open source XEDConvertApp](http://research.dwi.ufl.edu/ufdw/j4k/XEDConvertApp.php), which can be easily extended to save video as well. You can save the Video frames into PNG using the imageio.write and open it in Matlab. However, you need to map the pixels in the video images to the pixels depth in the depth frames. This can be easily done using the U,V mapping in Kinect SDK. You can save the UV coordinates using the source code which is available [here](http://research.dwi.ufl.edu/ufdw/j4k/examples.php#how). This example uses the J4K Java library for the Kinect SDK.